# Плохое качество картинки сохраненное на ImageView из intent camera в android studio

Tags: java, android

Код сохранения фотографии с камеры и отображения на ImageView

Проблема: Плохое качество картинки на ImageView

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {

            // Проверяем, содержит ли результат маленькую картинку
            if (data != null) {
                if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                        // TODO Какие-то действия с миниатюрой

                        //thumbnailBitmap = RotateBitmap(thumbnailBitmap, 90);
                        textView.setText(" ");
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnailBitmap);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        textView.setText("ошибка");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // TODO Какие-то действия с полноценным изображением,


                try{





                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mOutputFileUri);
                    bitmap = RotateBitmap(bitmap,90);
                    textView.setText(" ");



                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    textView.setText("ошибка");
                }

                // сохраненным по адресу mOutputFileUri

            }
        }
    }

    public  Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    private void saveFullImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

      try {



          mOutputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(FullscreenActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

      }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так  : 
код на вызов камеры:

```
String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
+ File.separator + "TakenFromCamera.jpg";
File file = new File(_path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

получить изображение

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +                File.separator + "TakenFromCamera.jpg";
            Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path);
            .....
        }
 }
```

Comment: CAMERA_REQUEST не находит, есть только CAM_RESULT, CAM_SERVICE

Comment: это уникальное число 
у меня это 
private int CAMERA_REQUEST = 434343; Сорян забыл

Comment: Хмм, стало вызывать камеру дважды, понимаешь, сохранённое в альбоме фото - хорошего качества, но на ImageView - плохое

Comment: значит ты где-то еще код вызываешь на камеру.  Если плохого качества - проверь , может быть где-то урезаешь качество.

Comment: где-то читал что 
 if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
возвращает размер иконки (маленькую картинку) поэтому качество тоже плохое. Попробуй мой способ - конкретно ты берешь файл .

Comment: Дада у меня вызывалась миниатюра, спасибо!

Comment: Есть на примете качественные статьи или видеоуроки по риссованию на ImageView?